# Logon failed IMOO2

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, deployment, vb6, crystal-reports

My company had a very old one form module developed in VB and back end is Access and I was forced to remove that system and re install this application to new system

I had succeed in doing the same and Data entry etc is working fine the only issue is when I am trying to give the print a crystal report form is opening which gives the below message.

[image]

I installed Microsoft Access and the db file is also in the directory folder.Can any one sugest any solution please

Comment: Have you reinstalled the ODBC driver and checked that the datasource the report is using is present on the computer?

Comment: Is it supposed to be opening a Crystal Report?  If so, do you have the correct Crystal Viewer installed?  If not, your file associations are likely set wrong for this.